# Unit testing for API call which return different data in jest - React JS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am learning more about testing React components using Jest and testing-library and have also started to implement the same in my project. i came across a scenario where a api call returns different data based on some scenarios. below are the 2 different response format from the api

```
records: [{
           "id": 33,
           "deviceId": "1234",
           "status": "ACTIVE"
           "customer": {
                    "email": "sams72@gmail.com",
                    "firstName": "Sam",
                    "lastName": "Dan",
                    "patientId": 43
           }
           },]
```

and

```
 records: [{
           "id": 33,
           "deviceId": "1234",
           "status": "ACTIVE"
           },]
```

Now i have the mock response in my test file as below

```
let mockGetDevices = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
        records: [{
            "id": 33,
            "deviceId": "1234",
            "status": "ACTIVE"
            "customer": {
                "email": "sams72@gmail.com",
                "firstName": "Sam",
                "lastName": "Dan",
                "patientId": 43
            }
        },]
    })
});


jest.mock('..//services/device.service', () => {
    return function () {
        return { getDevices: mockGetDevices };
    };
});


test("should make getdevice calls", async () => {
        const { getByTestId } = renderDeviceDetails();
        await waitFor(async () => {
            const switch = await getByTestId('deactivated-devices');
            fireEvent.change(switch);
            expect(mockGetDevices).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        })
    })
```

Above test case covers the scenario where the api response have ***customer*** in the response. i also want to test scenario where the response dont have ***customer***. How do i achieve this with jest where same api returns different dataset.

Note : i came across [mockImplementationOnce](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue) but doesn't seems to be ideal solution when the number of test cases are more.